# Combination of Possible Schedules for Employees

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

I have $10$ employees: Seven ($7$) of them are 'Regular', and Three ($3$) of them are 'Learner'. I need to schedule the work schedule (let's say $30$ days). Each day there are only two ($2$) employees are to work, and at least one ($1$) of them must be regular employee. The question is how many are there possible schedules?

The general question is, there are n employees ($n >= 1$). Of those, there are $k$ regular ones $(0 < k < n)$. The rest $(n - k)$ learner ones. Let's say each working day consists of two employees, at least one of the two must be regular one. The question is how many are there possible schedules for m working days?

My initial solution for the first question is:
Each working day: $C(7, 1) * C(3, 1) = 7 * 3 = 21$.
=> so $30$ days schedule, there are possible $30 * C(7, 1) * C(3, 1) = 30 * 21 = 630$ ways.

The same for the second question: there are possible: $m * C(n, k) * C(n, n-k)$ ways to schedule.

Yet, I'm still thinking there are something wrong with that. Could you help me verify the solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In your initial solution, based on $7$ regular and $3$ learner employees, your enumeration of $30 \times 21$ has two problems: [1] It is not $21 + 21 + \cdots + 21 = 30 \times 21$, but rather $21 \times 21 \times \cdots \times 21 = 21^{30}$.  Of course this large number assumes (for example) that you might have Regular-Person-1 + Learner-Person-1 work every day, while everyone else is idle.  Since this is impractical, you need to specify more constraints.  [2] Your computation **wrongly** assumes that you have to have 1 Regular + 1 Learner, which overlooks that you can instead have 2 Regulars.

Comment: Thank you @user2661923! 
Yes, I forgot the cases that both are Regular. Based on @Math Lover, it's 45 to the power of 30. I'm still verifying if something is missing...

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to remove cases that are not allowed. There are $10$ employees and total of $ ~ \displaystyle {10 \choose 2} = 45$ ways of choosing two employees. But as we cannot choose both as learners, we subtract $ \displaystyle {3 \choose 2}$.

So there are $42$ unique combinations of two employees such that at least one of them is *regular*.

*Now each day, you can choose one of the above combinations.*

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover! That's a better way of thinking!

Comment: @kangjmoon as you are new to the site, letting you know that if an answer helps you, you may want to consider accepting it by checking the tick mark on the left. For more details on how to accept an answer, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287